# Batch File - IF EXIST *.*

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to write a very simple small batch script to determine whether a directory contains ANY valid files and if it does then GOTO a copy command or Finish. However even when I know the directory T: is empty the following still thinks there is a file in there. Could it be some hidden or system files and how can I ignore these files?

```
IF EXIST T:\*.* goto STAGE1
goto FINISH
```

I had adapted a previous batch file which was specifically looking for *.TXT files however I can't be sure the new files will always be one particular type so I need the script to look for any file types. Are there any switches I can use?

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /a-d "t:\*.*" >nul 2>nul && goto stage1 || goto finish
```

If dir command does not found the indicated files (i've excluded subfolders), it will set errorlevel 1. So, check. If no errorlevel goto stage1, else goto finish

EDITED - To handle the case of subdirectories, excluding the hidden ones

```
dir /a-d "t:\" >nul 2>nul && goto stage1 
for /d /r "t:\" %%a in ("*") do ( dir /a-d "%%~fa\*" >nul 2>nul && goto stage1 )
goto finish
```

It will start checking the indicated folder and if no file is found, repeat the previous command for each of the directories in a recursive list. If any file is found, goto stage1. If for command finishes and next line is reached, goto finish.

Comment: That did work until the customer changed the goal posts and decided to drop a folder in the directory. How would I include the subfolders option? (excluding system folders)

Comment: @SuperSub, What do you mean with "system folders"?